# Embedding YouTube videos in older mobile browsers

Tags: html, video, mobile, youtube

So I'm working on a project and I'm using YouTubes iframe embed code and it'll work on newer devices like the iPhone and Android devices. However, when viewed on older Android and Blackberry I get a couple links about Getting newest Flash Player and Learn more about upgrading to a HTML5 browser. To remedy this I decided to try and embed the rstp link in the site and it worked on the older Androids but not the Blackberry

Does anyone know of anything that would make this simpler? I need to try to play the videos in all mobile browsers if possible and I've been looking for a day and not found much of anything. I thought about doing HTML5 and using the video tag, converting them to ogg, 3gp and mp4 or mpeg and let the browser show the correct one but again, still wont work on Blackberrys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for anyone that may come across something like this, this is what I came up with. It isn't pretty but it worked.

```
<script>
if ( !location.href.match(/mobile=no/) ) {
    var useragents = [['blackberry9700', 'blackberry9780'], ['android 1.5', 'android 1.6', 'android eclair', 'android 2.0', 'android 2.1']];

    var agt = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var mobile_type = 2;
    var i, j;

    for ( j=0; j<2; j++ ) {
        for ( i=0; i<useragents[j].length; i++ ) {
            if ( agt.indexOf(useragents[j][i]) != -1 ) {
                mobile_type = j;
                user_agent = agt;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( mobile_type == j ) break;
    }

    switch ( mobile_type ) {
        case 0:
            document.write("<a href='nan.3gp'><img src='videoimg.png' alt='' width='310' height='151' /></a>");
            break;
        case 1:
            document.write("<a href='nan2.m4v'><img src='videoimg.png' alt='' width='310' height='151' /></a>");
            break;
        default:
            document.write("<iframe width='312' height='192' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/aE2b75FFZPI?rel=0' type='text/html' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
    }
}
</script>
```